# How to POST a data value using @api_view in django rest api?

Tags: django, python-3.x, api, django-rest-framework

I have two APIs. From one API, I am sending string data to the second API. In the second API doing some calculation, I save a JSON format data in the API and send back the data to the first API. It is working. But in the second API, if I try to POST string data from the content box it shows error. Here the media type is "application/json". So how do I POST data from the API view? I have added the screenshot of the second API:

[input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPzlw.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilsiA.png)

Some portion of my views.py of the second API:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def sentenceList(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = Bucketlist.objects.all()
        serializer = BucketlistSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        triples = getTriples(request.data)
        keys = ['sub','predi','obj']
        demo_data = dict(zip(keys,triples[0]))
        serializer = BucketlistSerializer(data=demo_data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's your requirement, but, the error image says that ***you are not giving a `proper-JSON` data***

Comment: It gives the same error message if I give JSON data. But I want to give a sentence and build a JSON data to save in the database like the first picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write a custom parser for plaintext and use it in your view:

```
from rest_framework.parsers import BaseParser, JsonParser
from rest_framework.decorators import parser_classes

class PlainTextParser(BaseParser):
    """
    Plain text parser.
    """
    media_type = 'text/plain'

    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        """
        Simply return a string representing the body of the request.
        """
        return stream.read()
```

and your view:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@parser_classes((PlainTextParser, JsonParser))
def sentenceList(request):
...
```